# My media queries doesn't work

Tags: html, css, frontend

Does anyone know why my media queries code doesn't work?Thanks!

```
@media only screen and (min-width:450px){
  .dark-blue{
    width: 25%;
  }
  .blue{
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

More details in my github https://github.com/kmfb/udacityProjects/tree/master/column%20drop

Comment: check your viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I added it to my html, it didn't work.@Roy

Comment: CSS runs on a first occurance / first usage method, so putting rules at the **bottom** of a style sheet, or adding new style sheets **after** others will always ***Overwrite*** rules than have been set before.

Comment: That's the reason why I got an error. Thanks. @Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly depends on your project because at the end of the day it is all about maintenance and adding more stuff to it easily.

So, if you are working on a project which only has a few media queries I would suggest leaving them all at the bottom of your stylesheet but putting comments on top of it to make it explicit and also easier for you to find it later.

However, if you know you are going to have a lot of properties meticulously defined in your media queries and also have various devices defined then I would suggest separating them out just for readability/maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `@media` to the bottom of the css page.
Check working example.
Cheers, 
https://jsfiddle.net/frc7r123/

Comment: With your help, I did it! Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you need to place your media query below your other CSS. Otherwise it won't overwrite anything.

Comment: YES! You did help me.